# First order linear non-homogenous ode

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm learning how to solve ode and there's one thing in my lecture notes that I don't understand.

$y' +py = q \ $
$y(x_0) = y_0$

I understand that I can rewrite this to
$\phi = ce^{-P} + e^{-P} \int_{x_0}^{x}q(t)e^{P(t)}dt$

So I get:
$y_0 = \phi(x_0) = ce^{-P(x_0)} + e^{-P(x_0)} \int_{x_0}^{x_0}q(t)e^{P(t)}dt$

The integral being zero makes sense because of the bounds, but here I don't understand why it should be obvious to me that $P(x_0) = 0$

From which I can get $ c = \phi(x_0) = y_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y' +p(x)y = q(x) $$
Note that $P(x)$ is not the $p(x)$ in the DE. It comes as an integrating factor:
$$(ye^{\int p(x) dx})'=qe^{\int p(x)dx}$$
$$ye^{\int p(x) dx}=c+\int qe^{\int p(x)dx}dx$$
$$y=ce^{-\int p(x) dx}+e^{-\int p(x) dx}\int qe^{\int p(x)dx}dx$$
So that: $$P(x)=\int_{x_0}^x p(x)dx$$ And:  $$P(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^{x_0}p(x)dx=0$$